# Check if file is empty in Dart

Tags: json, dart

I'm trying to add new elements to my json file, to that end what I want to do is check if the `vault.json` is empty, if it is, write the first value of the json file like:
`[{"title":"ttt","description":"aagag","prio":0,"completed":false}]`,

but if its not empty, then remove the last char (`]`) and append the value like:
`,{"title":"ttt","description":"aagag","prio":0,"completed":false}]`.

Right now my code recreates de json file everytime is executed instead of appending the new value:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'ToDo.dart';

void main() async{
    print("hello");
    int prio1;
    print("Title:");
     String? title1 = stdin.readLineSync();
    print("description:");
     String? des = stdin.readLineSync();

    ToDo test = new ToDo(title1, des, 0, false);
    String  test11 = jsonEncode(test);

    print(test11);
    final filename = 'vault.json';
    new File(filename).writeAsString(test11+",");
}
```

```
class ToDo {
    String? title,description;
    int prio;
    bool completed;

    ToDo(this.title, this.description, this.prio, this.completed);

    ToDo.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json):
        title = json['title'],
        description = json['description'],
        prio = json['prio'],
        completed = json['completed'];

    Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => {
        'title':title,
        'description':description,
        'prio':prio,
        'completed':completed,
    };

}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `await File(filename).length == 0` will be true if the file is empty.  However, writing JSON manually seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: @jamesdlin what will you advise instead of manually writing them?

Comment: I would just use `jsonEncode` and rewrite the file.

Comment: Or not write the file as a sing-JSON-object file, but write, say, one JSON object per line, so you can just append a new line and not worry about the `,` or `]`.